# Open specific application from calendar item

Tags: java, android, android-calendar

Is it possible to open a specific application from within the description (or something else) from a calendar item?

(In iOS it is something like appname://....)

For example, I saved a meeting with a company in my calendar from within an application and when it is saved, the user should be able to return to the detail of that company in the app by using the event in the calendar.

Comment: Try to use [intent filter](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/intents-filters.html) for the issue.